# How to ask for administer privileges on Windows with Go

Tags: windows, go

What I want to achieve for my application, is to **not** need to right click and choose *Run as administrator* each time I want to run it. I want Windows to prompt me to gain admin permissions as with other windows applications.

consider the following code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    err := ioutil.WriteFile("C:/Windows/test.txt", []byte("TESTING!"), 0644)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
        time.Sleep(time.Second * 3)
    }
}
```

If you compile it and double click on it it will print:

> open: C:\Windows\test.txt: Access is denied.

But if you right-click and run as administrator, it will create and write the file.

How to make it ask for the admin permission just by double clicking on it?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need to embed a [manifest file](http://www.samlogic.net/articles/manifest.htm) which will tell Windows that you want elevated privileges.

The example from that page is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
<assemblyIdentity
    version="9.0.0.0"
    processorArchitecture="x86"
    name="myapp.exe"
    type="win32"
/>
<description>My App</description>
<trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <security>
        <requestedPrivileges>
            <requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false"/>
        </requestedPrivileges>
    </security>
</trustInfo>
</assembly>
```

This [go-nuts post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/shRlhV3Fe2E) suggests that using [rsrc](https://github.com/akavel/rsrc) should do the trick for you.

Answer (score 22):

This is the technique that I use to detect if I am running as administrator, and if not relaunch myself with a UAC prompt. This allows me to run as a standard user in most cases, and only elevate when needed. I use this in command line tools where most functions don't need admin rights, but functions like -install or -uninstall do since they're writing to HKLM in the registry or Program Files. No manifest is necessary with this method.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "golang.org/x/sys/windows"
    "os"
    "syscall"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    // if not elevated, relaunch by shellexecute with runas verb set
    if !amAdmin() {
        runMeElevated()
    }
    time.Sleep(10*time.Second)

}

func runMeElevated() {
    verb := "runas"
    exe, _ := os.Executable()
    cwd, _ := os.Getwd()
    args := strings.Join(os.Args[1:], " ")

    verbPtr, _ := syscall.UTF16PtrFromString(verb)
    exePtr, _ := syscall.UTF16PtrFromString(exe)
    cwdPtr, _ := syscall.UTF16PtrFromString(cwd)
    argPtr, _ := syscall.UTF16PtrFromString(args)

    var showCmd int32 = 1 //SW_NORMAL

    err := windows.ShellExecute(0, verbPtr, exePtr, argPtr, cwdPtr, showCmd)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
}

func amAdmin() bool {
    _, err := os.Open("\\\\.\\PHYSICALDRIVE0")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("admin no")
        return false
    }
    fmt.Println("admin yes")
    return true
}
```

More details available here:
https://gist.github.com/jerblack/d0eb182cc5a1c1d92d92a4c4fcc416c6

Comment: Excellent technique. Might come in handy in the future.

Comment: Don't you need to close the file if you are an admin?

Comment: what wrong with "windows.GetCurrentProcessToken().IsElevated()"...?

Comment: @trueToastedCode - The Token object couldn't support checking Elevated status until this commit: https://cs.opensource.google/go/x/sys/+/61b9204099cb1bebc803c9ffb9b2d3acd9d457d9

Same year, but I the question is when was it available for production use.