# How to create interactive command execution

Tags: go

My problem is the interaction with exec.command. I would like to automate RunAs on windows.

I want via this application launch other applications (eg Ccleaner, antivirus eset online, etc ...) on computers of my clients. So I create a adminsys account and I want to launch these various applications automatically with this account.

```
cmd := exec.Command("runas", user, nameProgram)

cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout
cmd.Stderr = os.Stderr

stdin, err := cmd.StdinPipe()
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
}
defer stdin.Close()
err = cmd.Start()
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
    return
}

time.Sleep(3 * time.Second)
io.WriteString(stdin, password)

err = cmd.Wait()
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
    return
}
```

This does not work!

The errors with runas.

```
Erreur de RUNAS : Impossible d’exécuter - C:\program.exe 
1326 : Le nom d’utilisateur ou le mot de passe est incorrect.
```

It looks like he does not recognize the password. This works when I do it directly in the command prompt

[image: gif]

Comment: Can you try: `exec.Command("cmd", "runas")` (Make sure your program has the administrative privileges to use `runas`

Comment: The command works,without `"cmd"`, but asks for a password. And I wish I could enter the password via go, not in the command prompt - @Tico

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31558066/how-to-ask-for-administer-privileges-on-windows-with-golang  The poster seems to have found a way!

Comment: Sorry I better explain myself. I want via this application launch other applications (eg Ccleaner, antivirus eset online, etc ...) on computers of my clients. So I create a adminsys account and I want to launch these various applications automatically with this account. @Tico

Comment: @samuelmichaux May be its better to edit your question and add your comment there

Comment: @boboes. Yes, I am sorry. I modified.

Comment: Oh, I see now @samuelmichaux. Do you get any error when trying to write your password to the stdin?

Comment: No errors with stdin. The errors with runas.
`Erreur de RUNAS : Impossible d’exécuter - C:\program.exe
1326 : Le nom d’utilisateur ou le mot de passe est incorrect.`

It looks like he does not recognize the password.
This works when I do it directly in the command prompt

Comment: Does it work if you change `io.WriteString(stdin, password)` to `io.WriteString(stdin, password + "\n")`?

Comment: @OneOfOne - It's same.

I added a gif to show the result

Answer (score 0):

I'm not running windows, and the code you have in your question works for me. So, the following may not solve your problem, but this is an alternative for passing string to a command.

I created this basic command named `pass` in order to assert the correctness of the password:

```
func main() {

    fmt.Print("Enter your password please: ")
    reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
    password, err := reader.ReadString('\n')
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("An error occurred while reading line")
    }

    // Remove the line break
    password = password[:len(password)-1]

    if password == "Secret pass" {
        fmt.Println("Success !")
    } else {
        fmt.Println("Failure !")
    }

}
```

Now, instead of working with pipe, set the `Stdin` of the command to a new reader:

```
func main() {
    cmd := exec.Command("pass")
    cmd.Stdin = strings.NewReader("Secret pass!\n")
    cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout
    _ = cmd.Run()
    // Failure

    cmd = exec.Command("pass")
    cmd.Stdin = strings.NewReader("Secret pass\n")
    cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout
    _ = cmd.Run()
    // Success
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: No change. It's the same thing. :-(