# Run unit test with admin rights

Tags: windows, go, admin-rights

I have a Go unit test. My code launches some external executables requiring *admin* rights for some of their features.

What's the easiest way to run my unit test with admin privileges? I have studied [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31558066/3405291) but I don't know how to do it for a unit test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm running the Go unit test again with the updated Go version `1.21.1` and see that the unit test is running just fine. I don't know why it's fixed now. Maybe the newest Go version runs the unit test with admin rights by default. Or else?